# Is a bounded convex function $g$ that is non-negative on this particular convex set also non-negative on the its closure?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, convex-analysis

#### Setup :

Let $S$ be the simplex on $\mathbb N$, i.e. the set of probability distribution on the natural numbers. Suppose we have $p\in S$ such that, for all $n\geq 1$, $p_n > 0$. For any $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq \mathbb N$, let $p^A\in S$ be defined as $p^A_n=\frac{p_n\cdot\mathbf 1(n\in A)}{\sum_{k\in A} p_n}$. Let $T$ be the convex hull of $\{ p^A : A\subseteq \mathbb N \}$, then for any reasonable topology on $S$, the closure of $T$ is $S$. We can for instance assume that $S$ is a subset of the Hilbert space on sequences with inner product

\begin{align*}
\langle q, r\rangle &= \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{q_n r_n}{p_n}
\end{align*}

#### Question :

> If $g:S\to\mathbb R$ is convex and bounded on $S$ as well as non-negative on $T$, then is $g$ non-negative on $S$ ?

#### Attempts :

In order to disprove this, I tried centering my space a $p$, then we can have a basis $\{ q_i \}_{i\in\mathcal I}$ for the span of $T$ and we can extend this basis  to the span of $S$ as $\{ q_i \}_{i\in \mathcal J}$ with $\mathcal I\subsetneq \mathcal J$. Then I set $g=0$ on $S$ and I tried setting $g(q_i)=-1$ for one of the $i\in\mathcal J\setminus \mathcal I$, but I think that this is bound to fail since $g$ is linear and bounded on $T$ and I believe this should imply, since it is also bounded on $S$, that it is linear and continuous on $S$, which means that $g=0$ on $S$, but then $g(q_i)=-1$ is impossible.

Comment: Where is $g$ convex and bounded? On $S$ or only on $T$?

Comment: Also, by "positive" do you actually mean "nonnegative"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis My bad, yes $g$ is convex and bounded on $S$ and non-negative on $T$. I edited accordingly.

Comment: Also, $A$ should be required to be nonempty. Also, your $T$ is the convex hull of the set of all extreme points of $S$.

Comment: Also, I think your Attempts should carefully edited.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes $A$ is nonempty, however I think that $T$ is actually larger than the convex hull of extreme points of $S$, indeed the extreme points are $e_i$ for all $i$ but $T$ can contain distribution with infinite support (like $p$). I am now rewording my attempt, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You are right, $T$ is bigger than that. Somehow, I forgot that $A$ can be infinite.

Comment: I think the question you ask in the title is not exactly the one asked in the text (this latter one has the trivial counterexample $g=0$, so the first one must be the one you wanted).

Comment: What is an example of a point in $S \setminus T$?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes sorry, all "positive" should be "non-negative", I edited.

Comment: @usul any probability distribution that has smaller or larger tail than $p$ would be in $S\setminus T$, so for instance $q_n \propto \frac{p_n}n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a nonprincipal ultrafilter $\omega$.
Given a point $x\in S$ with barycentric coordinates $(m_1,m_2,\dots)$, let
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \omega}(m_n\cdot n!).$$
It is an affine function on $S$ with values in $[0,\infty]$.
Note that
$$g=-\min\{f,1\};$$
is convex, bounded, and it is negative at some points.

Choose a point $p=(m_1,m_2,\dots)$ so that the sequence $m_n$ converges to zero very fast, say $m_n>n!\cdot m_{n+1}$ for all $n$.
Note that $f(p^A)=0$ for any $A$.
Therefore, $h|_T\equiv0$.